# Why people cannot load the image in my readme file, except for me

Tags: github, readme

I added an image in my readme file, I can load the image successfully, but others cannot.

```
<div align=center><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blablabka" ><img/></div>
```

[image]

But I asked my friend to open the link of this readme file, but he told me he cannot load the image successfully, like the screenshot shown below:
[image]

And I was wondering why this happened, and how to solve it?
Many thanks!

Comment: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blablabka` is not a valid image...

Comment: Yes, I modified the link of the image, just use blablaka to hide the real address, but I  can see my image.

Comment: How should any one help you when you censor the address?!